# How to install SonarQube with Open JDK 11

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-web

I am trying to install SonarQube 8.5 (community version) on my local machine . My machine already has Java `JRE 8` installed. SonaQube has pre-requirement `JRE 11` or `Open JDK 11`. Since you cannot download `JRE 11` anymore, I decided to go with `Open JDK 11`

I want to set SonarQube to use specific JDK. How do i do that?

Quick SO search suggest to use `wrapper.java.command` in `wrapper.conf` file, but this line is not available

SonarQube 8.5, OS Windows: 10

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want your sonarqube to use specific JDK i.e. in your case OpenJDK 11, rather than use JRE 8. You can create a user say `sonar`.

Give `sonar` user the ownership of all the installations of sonarqube. Set the path of  JAVA_HOME for OpenJDK11 for the user`sonar` only.

> Note: You have to start sonarqube using `sonar` user only.

Then , you can set SonarQube to use specific JDK

Answer (score 1):

According to [sonarqube community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/upgrading-to-7-9-version-sonarqube-requires-java-11-to-run/14836), you should do the following:

1. Edit `conf\wrapper.conf`, specifically the wrapper.java.command to following:

> wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\open jdk-11.0.2\bin\java
> #wrapper.java.command=java

Answer (score 0):

actually i found it
These doesn't exist by default, so I need to add these two lines into wrapper.conf

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\SonarQube\openjdk-11.0.2-win64\jdk-11.0.2\bin
wrapper.java.command=C:\SonarQube\openjdk-11.0.2-win64\jdk-11.0.2\bin\Java
```

Your installation base path may be different. But `bin` and `bin\Java` is important

Comment: Oh ok. Great :) When i will setup new sonarqube, i will try this out also.