# Sonarqube Critical error: wait for JVM process failed Windows

Tags: java, jvm, sonarqube

I am new at using Sonarqube and I have an issue that maybe you can help with.

I am working in a development project now that uses Jdk 8 update 261, so I have my environment variable JAVA_HOME pointing to it and I can not change it as suggested in other posts.

So I installed jdk 11 as you can see in this image:

[installed jdks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIFda.png)

And I edited my wrapper.conf to this:

[wrapper.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNtPe.png)

But still my sonarqube does not start. This is the log I get in my C:\sonarqube-7.9.5\logs\sonar file:

```
–> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM…
Unable to execute Java command. The system cannot find the specified file. (0x2)
“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4\bin\java.exe” -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8m -Xmx32m -Djava.library.path="./lib" -classpath “…/…/lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar;…/…/lib/common/activation-1.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-codec-1.12.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-csv-1.4.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-dbcp2-2.5.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-dbutils-1.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-email-1.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-io-2.6.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-lang-2.6.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-logging-1.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/commons-pool2-2.6.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/diffutils-1.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/elasticsearch-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/elasticsearch-cli-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/elasticsearch-core-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/elasticsearch-secure-sm-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/elasticsearch-x-content-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/gson-2.8.4.jar;…/…/lib/common/guava-18.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/hazelcast-3.12.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/hazelcast-client-3.12.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;…/…/lib/common/hppc-0.7.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/httpclient-4.5.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/httpcore-4.4.4.jar;…/…/lib/common/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar;…/…/lib/common/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar;…/…/lib/common/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.9.8.jar;…/…/lib/common/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.9.8.jar;…/…/lib/common/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.9.8.jar;…/…/lib/common/javax.mail-1.5.6.jar;…/…/lib/common/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/jbcrypt-0.4.jar;…/…/lib/common/jjwt-api-0.10.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/jjwt-impl-0.10.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/jjwt-jackson-0.10.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/jna-4.5.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/joda-time-2.10.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/jopt-simple-5.0.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;…/…/lib/common/log4j-api-2.8.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/log4j-to-slf4j-2.8.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/logback-access-1.2.3.jar;…/…/lib/common/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;…/…/lib/common/logback-core-1.2.3.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-analyzers-common-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-backward-codecs-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-core-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-grouping-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-highlighter-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-join-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-memory-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-misc-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-queries-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-queryparser-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-sandbox-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-spatial-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-spatial-extras-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-spatial3d-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lucene-suggest-7.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/lz4-1.3.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/mybatis-3.5.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/nanohttpd-2.3.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-buffer-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-codec-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-codec-http-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-common-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-handler-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-resolver-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/netty-transport-4.1.32.Final.jar;…/…/lib/common/okhttp-3.14.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/okio-1.17.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/parent-join-client-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/percolator-client-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/picocontainer-2.15.jar;…/…/lib/common/protobuf-java-3.7.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;…/…/lib/common/snakeyaml-1.17.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-ce-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-ce-common-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-ce-task-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-ce-task-projectanalysis-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-channel-4.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-check-api-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-classloader-1.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-core-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-db-core-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-db-dao-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-db-migration-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-duplications-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-main-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-markdown-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-plugin-api-7.9.5-all.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-plugin-api-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-process-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-scanner-protocol-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-server-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-server-common-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-update-center-common-1.18.0.487.jar;…/…/lib/common/sonar-ws-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/common/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;…/…/lib/common/staxmate-2.0.1.jar;…/…/lib/common/t-digest-3.2.jar;…/…/lib/common/tomcat-annotations-api-8.5.38.jar;…/…/lib/common/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.38.jar;…/…/lib/common/transport-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/transport-netty4-client-6.8.0.jar;…/…/lib/common/woodstox-core-lgpl-4.4.0.jar;…/…/lib/sonar-application-7.9.5.jar;…/…/lib/sonar-shutdowner-7.9.5.jar” -Dwrapper.key=“PxSC6cpdcoyZnBC3” -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=4596 -Dwrapper.version=“3.2.3” -Dwrapper.native_library=“wrapper” -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=“10” -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.sonar.application.App
Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message (in Spanish) says "The system cannot find the specified file." Did you check that java is really installed in the specified path?

Here are two related resources:

- [How to install SonarQube with Open JDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493276/how-to-install-sonarqube-with-open-jdk-11)
- https://community.sonarsource.com/t/java-11-not-detected-although-it-is-installed/14160